# M test (Weierstrass)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hi Good Day i cam across a question shown below :-

Prove the following series is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nsin^3(n+x^2)}{n^2\pi^2+1}$$

I was trying to evaluate the question was hoping someone can correct me or guide me.
I know that the M test considers
A $M_n$ > 0 such that |$f_n(x)$| $\leq$ $M_n$

Then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$$ conforms uniformly if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n$$ converges

My solution thus far

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nsin^3(n+x^2)}{n^2\pi^2+1}$$

I know that for $sin^3(n+x^2)\leq 1$ Therefore this implies the following

$$\frac{|(-1)^nsin^3(n+x^2)|}{n^2\pi^2+1} \leq \frac{(1)^n}{n^2\pi^2+1} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$

The expression that i am left with is 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1)}{n^2}$$ can anyonle tell me if the evaluation was done correctly?

Comment: $|(-1)^n|=1{}$.

Comment: @ThomasShelby hence i would be left with $1/n^2$ ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\lt\infty.$

Comment: are you implying that when substituting n as infinity the value will be 0 ? @ThomasShelby thank you for confirming this question and showing me my mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are left with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$. This is convergent as a $p$-series with $p>1$. Thus you can already conclude by the Weierstrass $M$-test that the series is uniformly convergent for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: thank you for the information and the conclusion.